# Python multiproccesing.Procces does not run in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, multiprocessing

Why do processes of a code below not work in parallel?

When I am running the code I am waiting that it will run in parallel but it first waits when the first process will finish, then the second and so on. Nothing runs in parallel. Probably I have a blind spot in execution Python code in parallel.

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def run1(name):
   print("Proccess", name, "has started")
   time.sleep(2)
   print("Proccess", name, "has finished")


def run2(name):
   print("Proccess", name, "has started")
   time.sleep(3)
   print("Proccess", name, "has finished")


start_time = time.time()
pr1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=run1('A'), )
pr1.start()
print('-')

pr2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=run1('B'))
pr2.start()
print('-')

pr3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=run2('C'))
pr3.start()
print('-')

end_time = time.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because instead of passing a target function
You call it...
`Target=func`
Not `target=func ()`